# PyQt6 QScroller: How to Prevent Scroll Interruption on Click?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qscrollarea

I'm working on a PyQt application with QPdfView and QScroller to implement a PDF viewer. I've set up scrolling, but I'm facing an issue where the user can stop the scrolling by clicking on the screen during the scroll.

Here's a snippet of my current code:

```py
# Relevant code snippet
self.scroller.scrollTo(QPointF(0, top_of_page)
```

I want to disable the ability for the user to interrupt the scroll by clicking on the screen. I've explored QScroller's documentation, but I haven't found a clear solution.

Any help or guidance on how to prevent scroll interruption during a QScroller scroll would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway, you need to implement a custom gesture recognizer, but it's not well documented.